# Relation between two sets of generators of SO(3)

Tags: lie-algebras, representation-theory

I am working with the spin 1 representation of SU(2), which is just SO(3). The ordinary generators used in quantum mechanics are:

$J_x = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$;      $J_y = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & -\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 \\
 \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & -\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} \\
 0 & \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$;        $J_z = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$.

But I can also work with just the ordinary 3D rotation matrices that rotate vectors specified by (x,y,z) components. From taking the infinitesimal limit of these matrices, I find that the generators are:

$J_x' = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -i \\
 0 & i & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right);       J_y' = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & i \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -i & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right);       J_z' = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & -i & 0 \\
 i & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$.

After exponentiating, I get rotation operators $D(\psi,\theta,\phi)$ and $D'(\psi,\theta,\phi)$, where the $D$ operators act on vectors written in the j=1, m =-1,0,1 basis and the $D'$ operators act on vectors written in a different basis.

What is the relation between these two operators (or between the generators)? Are they related by a unitary transformation? If so, how does one go about finding that unitary transformation? (That is what I first suspected, but I was unable to find any unitary transformation that works.) Or are they not related in a direct way?

EDIT:
Corrected sign error in generators.

Comment: I would try to diagonalize $J'_z$ and take the eigenvectors in the order for which they will give you $J_z$. Then use them to define the unitary that hopefully takes the other primed generators to the unprimed (or viceversa).

Comment: That worked. After finding the eigenvectors I just had to be careful to choose their phase to make sure the transformation workss out for all 3 matrices. Thanks!

Comment: @syhpphys You can answer your own question once you figure it out! In fact, that's best, so that people who visit the page and skim won't go thinking there isn't an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the suggestion of Phoenix87, we can find the unitary transformation by noticing that the transformation that diagonalizes $J_z'$ will also transform $J_z'$ to into $J_z$ (since $J_z$ is diagonal). So we find the eigenvectors of $J_z'$ and then use them as the columns of our unitary transformation. We are free, however, to choose the phase of the eigenvectors, and so we make the choice that gives $U^\dagger J_x' U = J_x$ and $U^\dagger J_y' U = J_y$. When all is said and done, we obtain:

$U = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} \\
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
 0 & i & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$.

Which gives $U^\dagger J_i' U = J_i$.